# How can I use the Array Mixin in Ember?

Tags: arrays, ember.js

I'm trying to understand how to use [Ember.Array](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html). The document says to implement `replace` and `objectAt` but I can't find any information about what inputs it expects and an example would be very helpful.

Comment: How are you trying to use it?  That might sway my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just use `Ember.ArrayProxy` it already has the methods implemented, and it's likely you wouldn't implement them any different than they did.  Or, you can use it for a reference point: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.5.0/packages/ember-runtime/lib/system/array_proxy.js#L221.

Here's the api signature if you wanted to do it anyway:

```
var MyCoolArrayType = Em.Object.extend(Em.Array, {
  replace: function(idx, amt, objects){

  },

  objectAt: function(idx){

  }
}
```